# Jasmine which file controls what specs are run

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I thought it was `SpecRunner.html` but changing that doesn't affect running my spec.

My specs are in `spec/` and my source code is in `src/`

Answer (score 1):

Configure *this* file:

```
spec/javascript/support/jasmine.yml
```

Put values for `src` and `spec` (existing sections within the file) like this:

```
src_files: 
  - src/**/*.js
```

and

```
spec_files: 'spec/**/*[Ss]pec.js'
```